# Как в bootstrap растянуть содержимое контейнера на всю ширину страницы?

Tags: html, bootstrap

Есть такая разметка:

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="head">
     Logo
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
    
</div>
```

У блока `container` ширина не была на всю страницу, и при этом еще отступы слева и справа.

Добавил css:

```css
.container {
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 width: 100%;
}
```

и теперь появилась горизонтальная полоса прокрутки.

что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для этого в `bootstrap` используется класс `container-fluid`

Пример

```css
[class*=container] {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  container
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  container-fluid
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Используй `container-fluid`. 
Или следующую структуру:

```
body
    .фон
       .container
```